# SQL INSERT from HTML Input with checking for already existing

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, insert

With a HTML/php Webinterface i am putting some variables to a mysql datebase.
The query works fine like this:

`INSERT INTO ". $tabledb_stack ." (ANr, Operator) VALUES ('". $ANr ."', '". $Operator ."')`

But now i need to check if the ANr Value is already in the database.
But just the ANr number and no other Value. Then it should not write it into the database.
I tried with a WHERE NOT EXISTS statement, but it isnt working.

Any hints how i can try it?

Thx

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: use select query with where condition and check ANr  in table if exists don't insert else insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ANr` column has a primary or unique key assigned to it, then it is possible to use `INSERT INTO x ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ANr = ANr` so it will not update any rows, if the `ANr` will have any existing rows not depending on `Operator` column.

In case `ANr` can have more than one `Operator` it is possible to use `INSERT IGNORE INTO`. Thus it will ignore the insert, if there will be an existing row with `ANr + Operator` already.

For more information, feel free to read MySQL documentation here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html